# Ruby, deploying an exe with ocra that contains the TK GUI

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

Ocra is unable to handle applications that require 'tk'

```
require 'tk'
puts 'nope'
```

Packing this code with 
**ocra** http://github.com/larsch/ocra
doesn't work (like mentioned in one of the issues at the link)
Issue: https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/29

(Ocra is the 'new' rubyscript2exe for 1.9, essentially it's for deploying a rb script as an executable)

The only problem seems to be the missing DLL files for tcl

I don't think it's an issue

AFAIK the problem are the missing DLL files for tk
If they are known they can be included when executing ocra

Is there a way to know the DLL dependecies required for tk to work?

Comment: I didn't look on the issue tracker today... it is solved already (some hours ago), sorry.

    ocra.bat .\lib\main.rb --windows C:\Ruby192\lib\tcltk\ --no-autoload --add-all-core

(add all core is optional, don't include it if the exe works without it)

--> http://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/29

Comment: If you tried it and it worked, you should post this as an aswer and accept it (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't look on the issue tracker today... it is solved already (some hours ago), sorry.

```
ocra rubyfile.rb --windows C:\Ruby192\lib\tcltk\ --no-autoload --add-all-core
```

(--add-all-core is optional, don't include it if the exe works without it)

--> https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/29

Comment: Note: ordering is important!  Follow the parent's example.

Comment: None of this works for me. When I use `ocra file.rb --windows...` I get a require cannot load such file. When I use `bundle exec ocra file.rb --windows ....`, the program will appear, but then give an error about it doesn't know what to do with the .gitignore. `ERROR: Don't know where to put gemfile C:/Users/user1/Desktop/ruby-tk/tk_02/.gitignore`