# How to build executable from a ruby-tk project?

Tags: ruby, binaryfiles

I have a `ruby-tk` project and I would like to get a standalone binary. I am working on **OSX** and would like a binary for **Windows**, **OSX**, **Linux**. Is there a tool for that ? I tried `ruby2exe`, `ruby2app`, `ocra`, but none seem to do all of it.

Comment: Do you look for one tool to create executables for each system? Or do you have specific problems with one system. (for ocra and tk see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510748/ruby-deploying-an-exe-with-ocra-that-contains-the-tk-gui )

Comment: Yes I want a binary for each platform. One code, every platform. Ocra seem to solve windows but not linux and osx.

Answer (score 0):

There is **[Platypus](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus)** – which, according to its description, “creates native Mac applications from interpreted scripts such as shell scripts or Perl and Python programs.”

But there is no mention of Tk support in its Github repo.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into Platypus but it seems to solve only osx.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read your question thoroughly. I thought you were looking for OSX only :(